# How to Use Images from Texture Atlas in CocosBuilder?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I am attempting to build a Cocos2d level using a Texture Atlas which contains building images inside of it.

How do I accomplish this in CocosBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocosBuilder supports texture atlases, so if your CCB project files are in the same location as your textureatlas.plist and textureatlas.png, they will show up in the list of resources in CocosBuilder.  You can then use them in the CCB interface just like any other image file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. However, I found this quick tutorial to be very helpful in learning CocosBuilder: [creating-a-game-with-ccb](http://code.zynga.com/2012/10/creating-a-game-with-cocosbuilder/).